# Consuming from a Kafka topic that requires authentication using reactor kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, reactive-programming, spring-kafka, jaas, reactor-kafka

I have a micro-service that consumes from a Kafka topic that requires authentication. Below is the code I wrote for that. I am fetching the username and password from environment variables that I am sure is working as expected.

```
val receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer(defaultKafkaBrokerConfig.getAsProperties())
val kafkaJaasConfig = String.format(
    "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='%s' password='%s';",
    kafkaUsername,
    kafkaPassword
)
val schedulerKafkaConsumer = Schedulers.newSingle("consumer")
val options = receiverOptions
    .subscription(topicConfig.topics)
    .pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(topicConfig.pollWaitTimeoutMs.toLong()))
    .consumerProperty(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "SCRAM-SHA-512")
    .consumerProperty(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, kafkaJaasConfig)
    .consumerProperty(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT")

    return KafkaReceiver.create(options)
        .receive()
        .subscribeOn(schedulerKafkaConsumer) 
        .map { record: ReceiverRecord<ByteBuffer, ByteBuffer> -> handleConsumerRecord(record) }
        .onErrorContinue { throwable: Throwable?, _: Any? ->
            log.error(
                "Error consuming and deserializing messages",
                throwable
            )
        }
```

The code works fine when I run it locally. However, on GCP development environment, i get the following error:

```
Bootstrap broker <<some_ip>>:9093 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-service_gcp-edge_6ef14fcc-3443-4782-aa38-0910a5aea9b9-2, groupId=service_gcp-edge_6ef14fcc-3443-4782-aa38-0910a5aea9b9] Connection to node -1 (kafka0-data-europe-west4-kafka.internal/<<some_ip>>:9093) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.
```

Upon bashing into the cluster, I could connect to the topic and consume messages with a command line tool and so it removes the possibility of any infra related issue.

Can someone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?